# Sorting Students by Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a **Student** model with **name:string** and **classroom:string** columns.

I wish to have a page that list students from each class.

i.e. 
localhost:3000/students/1E1
     localhost:3000/students/1E2
     localhost:3000/students/1E3 
etc

I cannot seem to work things out. This is my first Rails app I tried to work on my own. But I am really stuck! Hope someone can help me out.

**This code is in my students_controller.rb**

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @students = Student.all
  end

  def show
    @student = Student.find(params[:id])
  end


  def sort_by_class
    @student = Student.find(params[:id])
    @class = @student.classroom
  end

end
```

**This code is in my show.html.erb**

```
<h1>Students#show</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/students/show.html.erb</p>


<%= @student.name %>
<%= @student.classroom%>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better if you make "classroom" as model and associate to student:

### **m-n Association for Student and Classroom: [The has_and_belongs_to_many Association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)**

generate in terminal:

```
rails g model classroom number:string
rails g migration create_classrooms_student classroom:references student:references
```

**models/student.rb**

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many :classrooms

end
```

**models/classroom.rb**

```
class Classroom < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many :students

end
```

### **OR 1-n Association for Student and Classroom:**

generate in terminal:

```
rails g model classroom number:string
rails g migration add_classroom_id_to_students classroom:references
```

**models/student.rb**

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :classroom

end
```

**models/classroom.rb**

```
class Classroom < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :students

end
```

### controller for both example

**controllers/classrooms_controller.rb**

```
class ClassroomsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @classrooms = Classroom.all
  end

  def show
    @classroom = Classroom.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<h1><%= @classroom.number %></h1>

<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th> Name </th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @classroom.students.each do |student| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= student.name %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

your URL:

```
localhost:3000/classrooms/1E1
```

Comment: When creating relation use `<field>:references`. It will automatically create index on that field.

Comment: Thank you guys. Now I get it. Didnt think Classroom as a model makes total sense.  ... Learning is great with kind and generous people like yourselves. Thank you again. :)

Comment: @Exsemt also remove `_id` suffix as it od now unneded.

Answer (score 0):

Is sort_by_class another route or do you want to sort by class in the index?

Assuming that classroom is an association to student (belongs_to :classroom) and you have a classroom_id column in the Student table, you can do something like Student.order(:classroom_id)

Comment: I just want to have pages like these...localhost:3000/students/1E1
localhost:3000/students/1E2
localhost:3000/students/1E3. So should :classroom be another model? or should it be one the Student attributes?

Answer (score 0):

or simple way for you:

**create new controller for classroom**

```
class ClassroomsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @classrooms = Student.group(:classroom).pluck(:classroom)
  end

  def show
    @classroom = params[:id]
    @students = Student.where(params[:id])
  end
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<h1>Classrooms</h1>
<table>
  <% @classrooms.each do |classroom| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= classroom %></td>
      <td><%= link_to(classroom, classroom_path(classroom)) %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<h1>Classroom <%= @classroom %> Students</h1>
<table>
  <% @students.each do |student| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= student.name %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```